# Display data as Tree angular

Tags: angular

I am trying to display the people data as a tree with a filter following "select fields: area", does angular give a possibility to display the data in this form  ? and how can I do it?
I have data in this structure

```
public rowData = [
{
  area : area A',
  Persons: [
    { person:  'person 1', position :'lvl 1' , sup: '' } ,
    { person:  'person 2', position :'lvl 2' , sup :'person 1' }, 
    { person:  'person 3', position :'lvl 2' , sup :'person 1'  } ,
    { person:  'person 4', position :'lvl 3' , sup :'person 3'} ,
    { person:  'person 5', position :'lvl 3' , sup :'person 4'} ,
    { person:  'person 6', position :'lvl 3' , sup :'person 5'} ,
    { person:  'person 7', position :'lvl 4' , sup :'person 6'} 
  
},
{
  area : area B',
  Persons: [
    { person:  'person 21', position :'lvl 1' , sup :''} ,
    { person:  'person 22', position :'lvl 2' , sup :'person 1'}, 
    { person:  'person 23', position :'lvl 2' , sup :'person 1'} ,
    { person:  'person 24', position :'lvl 3' , sup :'person 2'} ,
    { person:  'person 25', position :'lvl 3' , sup :'person 2'} ,
   
  
},
  ]
```

[image]

Comment: did u tried something ?

Comment: @HadesZazif yes just html and css

Comment: try https://www.zingchart.com/docs/integrations/angular

Comment: @Eliseo there is nothing like what I said in Zingchart

Comment: Sorry, I see that has an angular and don't read any more :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm working on create a TreeView Graphic in pure Angular.  To not "re-invent the wheel" I copied the code from this old [CodeProject article](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16192/Graphic-JavaScript-Tree-with-Layout)

I put the code in [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-igtvfl?file=src%2Fapp%2Feconode.ts)

It's hard (and too large) explain all the code, futhermore I need to do some cleanup because there are functions that are not implemented

### Usage

Basically you need to copy the `tree-view.component.ts` and the `econode.ts`. Works simply using

```html
    <tree-view #treeView [data]="data" [template]="treeTemplate"> 
    </tree-view>
    <ng-template #treeTemplate let-node>
      {{node.data.id}}
    </ng-template>
```

Where `data` is a typical object with children. The nodes are of type `IECONode`
in the way

```js
    export interface IECONode
    {
      data:any;
      linkColor?:string;
      background?:string;
      color?:string;
      width?:number;
      height?:number;
      children?:IECONode[];
    }
```

And the properties are inherited from the parent elements

- NOTE: As I update the code, I'll update this post *

### Update 1

I improved the component adding three functions:

1. `getChildren`
2. `getParent`
3. `getSlibingNodes`

Futhermore, I got out the `div` element. the template is more complex but allows usage of `(click)` or `(mouseover)` to select one node or its parent/children.

Only the "nodes" are "colored" if they are selected, and only the "lines" are "colored" if go to a node selected.

This allow, e.g. select the nodes in a mouse over (or in a click)

```html
    <ng-template #treeTemplate let-node>
      <div class="item" (mouseover)="selectSlibingNodes(treeView,node)" 
            [ngStyle]="node.isSelected?{'background-color':node.bc,color:node.c}:null">
      {{node.data.id}}
      </div>
    </ng-template>
```

The function `selectSlibingNodes` like:

```js
      selectSlibingNodes(treeView: TreeViewComponent, node: ECONode) {
        if (node==this.nodeSelected) {
          this.nodeSelected=null;
          treeView.nodes.forEach(x => {
            x.isSelected = false;
          });
        } else {
          this.nodeSelected=node;
          const nodes = treeView.getSlibingNodes(node).map(x => x.id);
          treeView.nodes.forEach(x => {
            x.isSelected = x.id == node.id || nodes.indexOf(x.id) >= 0;
          });
        }
      }
```

I made a [new stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-d6wmqn?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftree-view.component.ts) with the changes

Comment: I used another Method using GOJS library , I get the same graph that I  draw in the post but the library is not for free . I will try ur  solution and go back for you . Thank you for your reply . I ll accept it as answer

Comment: Thanks to @JoSSte to check and edit my "terrorific english"

Answer (score 0):

you can use `angular2-tree-diagram` package

[angular2-tree-diagram](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-tree-diagram)